# Code that works fine on local but not on server

Tags: php, curl, server

So the purpose of my code is to get response from curl.

**Here is a reference method**

```
public function waybill($waybill, $courier)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        [Some CURLOPT here..]
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        return "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        return $response;
    }
}
```

**And from here i call the method**

```
public function getWaybill($carrier, $tracking_number)
{
    $waybill = $tracking_number;
    $courier = strtolower($carrier);

    $response = $this->helper->waybill($waybill, $courier);
    $response = json_decode($response, true);
    $response = $response['rajaongkir']['result'];
    $response = $response['summary']['status'];
    if (!empty($response)) {
        return $response;
    } else {
        return "Invalid tracking data";
    }
}
```

In local appear "Invalid tracking data" if response is empty, however in server does not appear anything.

Comment: Turn error reporting on and see what's the reason

Comment: For debugging purposes use `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Maybe curl extension is switched off on your server?

Comment: are you trying to curl a https url? Do you have certificates installed properly?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating another page with just this on it

```
<?php
    if (in_array ('curl', get_loaded_extensions())) {
    echo true;
}
else {
    echo false;
}
```

This will let you know if curl is enabled (`if get_loaded_extensions()` isn't disabled) ... Might be your issue..
Otherwise the old

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

and search for curl would work too (if phpinfo is allowed on your server)